# Why do Samsung S7 battery drains fast then usual when I walk with the phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

I am using Samsung S7 for last one month. I have noticed

1. When I am sitting in my room, then the battery drains as usual.
2. But when I walk with the phone in my pocket the battery drains really really quick.

I saw the battery usage one of my friend who uses Samsung s6, it also situation as mine. Can anyone please give me a solution for this.

Comment: If it drains quickly when moving its usually location based services... Try disabling Google Now, change location to battery saver, turn off Google location tracker, etc

Comment: @acejavelin hey thank you very much. Can you please give me a link of services of the apps I should disable in order to save the battery.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by "acejavelin" in the comment section, location based services seem to be the main culprit in your case. Here are the things, you can try to improve your battery life:

- Always turn off the location services on your Android when not in use. And, when you use location services, change the Location Mode to “Battery Saving” to save the battery life. Also, turn off the location history on your device in the Google location settings. You might find this article, useful: http://trendblog.net/disable-location-services-android/
- Turn off 'Google Now/Ok Google' on your device: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2824784?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en Saw a great improvement after turning this feature off on my Galaxy S6.

Hope it helps!